# How can i insert new node between node index

Tags: java

i am doing object oriented programming project first time in Java
below is my some workings
Quetion: i unable to add new node in specific index. in my linkedlist class i do loop to printout list of node from head it show the result as per below: < red, blue, orange, green > but i unable to place new node between them. for example new node with pink color how i can add before blue node
any help or suggestion?

ListApp

```
public class ListApp {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Node n4 = new Node("green", null);
        Node n3 = new Node("orange", n4);
        Node n2 = new Node("blue", n3);
        Node n1 = new Node("red", n2);

        LinkedList list = new LinkedList(n1);
        System.out.println(list.getHead().getItem());

        System.out.println("\n" );

        list.deleteBefore(n2);
        System.out.println(list);       

    }
}
```

Node class

```
package lib;

public class Node {
    private String item;
    private Node nextItem;

    public Node(String str, Node n){
        item = str;
        nextItem = n;
    }
    public String getItem(){
        return item;
    }
    public void setItem(String str){
        item = str;
    }
    public Node next(){
        return nextItem;
    }
    public void setNext(Node n){
        nextItem = n;
    }
}
```

LinkList class

```
public class LinkedList {
    private Node head;

    public LinkedList(Node h){
        head = h;
    }
    public Node getHead(){
        return head;
    }
    public void setHead(Node n){
        head = n;
    }

    public void insertAfter(Node newNode, Node prev){
        newNode.setNext(prev.next());
        prev.setNext(newNode);
    }

    public void deleteAfter(Node prev){
        if ( prev.next() != null ){
        prev.setNext(prev.next().next());
        }   
        else prev.setNext(prev.next()); //BECAUSE THERE IS NOTHING TO PRINT OUT.
    }

    public void changeNextItem(Node n, String str){
        if (n.next() != null)
        n.next().setItem(str);
    }

    public void replaceAfter( Node newNode, Node Prev){
        newNode.setNext(Prev.next());
        Prev.setNext(newNode);
    }

    public void changeAll(String colour){
        Node current = head;
        while (current != null){
            current.setItem("white");
            current = current.next();
        }
    }

    public String toString(){
        String str = "";
        Node current = head;
        while(current != null){
            str = str + current.getItem();
            current = current.next();
            if (current != null){
                str = str + ", ";
            }
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's very unclear what your question is. Please use proper grammar and tell us exactly what you are trying to do, and what problems you are having.

Comment: sorry for that
actually i unable to add new node in specific index.
in my linkedlist class i do loop to printout list of node from head it show the result as per below:
<  red, blue, orange, green >
but i unable to place new node between them. for example new node with pink color how i can add before blue node

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Could you add that to the question itself so everyone can see it more easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell, it sounds like you are trying to insert a new Node into the middle of your LinkedList after a certain existing Node. Your LinkedList class has an insertAfter method which looks correct. Try calling that method from main(). For example, if you wanted to add a new Node containing the string "pink" after the node n3, you could write this:

```
list.insertAfter(new Node("pink", null), n3);
```

If you want to add a Node before a given existing Node, you could write a method in LinkedList very similar to insertAfter, except you would have to either add a reference to the previous Node into your Node class, or loop through and find the previous Node inside the insertBefore() method. Something like this:

```
public void insertBefore(Node newNode, Node existingNode){
    Node current = head;
    Node prev = null;
    while(current != null){
        if(current.getItem().equals(existingNode.getItem())){
            prev.setNext(newNode);
            newNode.setNext(current);
            break;
        } else{
            prev = current;
            current = current.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it seam perfect: 
how can i add new node before given node

Comment: OR 
how can i remove the previous index before given node
for example: this code < list.insertAfter(new Node("pink", null), n3); > successfully add pink after given. in same way how to remove pink node before n3. Well till now whatever you provide is great for me.

Comment: deletebefore

public void deletBefore(Node newNode, Node before)
 {
  if (before != null){
   Node current = head;
   Node prev = null;
   System.out.println("--------------------------------");
   while(current != before){
    prev = current;
    System.out.println(prev.getItem());
    System.out.println(current.next().getItem());
    current = current.next();
   }
   System.out.println("--------------------------------");
   newNode.setNext(before);
   prev.setNext(newNode);
  }
 }

Comment: I'm not sure what the code in your last comment is. But I have edited my answer to add one way you could implement an insertBefore() method. Does that fully answer your question?